# Using functions from one source file in another - Haskell

Tags: haskell

I have file1.hs that is NOT a module that has two functions in it.  I also have file2.hs that has main in it and I'm wondering if it's possible to use a function from file1 in file2. 
file2 reads in a .txt file from command line args so the way I've been doing it is:

```
ghc --make file2
```

then,

```
file2.exe input.txt
```

Is accessing functions across files possible without making one a module?

Comment: In a word no, but you could either move the common function to another file and import it in both, or make the original file a module

Comment: But isn't that literally, exactly the purpose of modules?

Comment: Can you say why you want to avoid making it a module? Perhaps we can offer some other way to achieve your real goals.

Comment: It is an assignment and file1 was given to us and I can't alter it without causing an error when it is graded.  I guess I'll just copy the functions into all of the files I need to use them in.  I was just wondering if there was another way without having to define the same function in 5 different files and not rewrite the file to be a module.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the C preprocessor if your implementation supports it.

```
-- file2.hs
{-# LANGUAGE CPP #-}
module Main where

#include "file1.hs"

main = print $ foo 42
```

and

```
-- file1.hs

foo x = x * 2
```

That it is possible does not necessarily mean that it is a good idea, though. Just use modules.

Comment: For testing purposes this the best solution, thanks,